# Declaration of Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::is() must be compatible with Bican\Roles\Contracts\HasRoleAndPermission::is($role, $all = false)

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3

### I cant attach user to there role;

here is my user model ##

```
>use Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable;
>use Bican\Roles\Traits\HasRoleAndPermission;

>use Bican\Roles\Contracts\HasRoleAndPermission as HasRoleAndPermissions;
>use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable as AuthenticatableContract;
>use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\CanResetPassword as CanResetPasswordContract;
>use Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\CanResetPassword;
>use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
>use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;
>use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;

>class User extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract, >CanResetPasswordContract, HasRoleAndPermissions
>{
 >   use Authenticatable, CanResetPassword, HasRoleAndPermission, Notifiable;
```

Comment: have you implemented the contract methods ?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose there is a 
`is()`
 function in the core Model class itself that is conflicting with your interface. Or maybe it's showing error because you haven't included any arguments in the implemented 
`is($role, $all)`
 method in the User model.

Comment: Yes there a conflict of is() in laravel 5.3 cause in laravel 5.2 it works

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem with Laravel 5.3 then I change is() method to isRole(). Please follow repository [link](https://github.com/romanbican/roles/pull/189) and change all file as mention there.

Answer (score 0):

use this step to fix this:

***step one:*** Add VCS Repo to your composer.json
"repositories": `[ { "type": "vcs", "url": "https://github.com/nikolaynesov/roles.git" } ]`

***step two:*** Change version of the package in *composer.json*

"bican/roles": "dev-master",
[Roman Bincan issue solved](https://github.com/romanbican/roles/issues/190)